# Getting content of href value

Tags: php, href

I need to catch the content of href using regex. For example, when I apply the rule to
href="www.google.com", I'd like to get www.google.com. Also, I would like to ignore all hrefs which have only # in their value.

Now, I was playing around for some time, and I came up with this:

```
href=(?:\"|\')((?:[^#]|.#.|.#|#.)+)(?:\"|\')
```

When I try it out in http://www.rubular.com/ it works like a charm, but I need to use it with preg_replace_callback in PHP, and there I don't get the expected result (for testing it in PHP, I was using this site: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm).

What's my mistake here?

Comment: First and foremost: [DON'T USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since parsing HTML using regular expressions is a [Bad Thing™](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I suggest a less crude method:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($pageContent);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

for ($n = 0; $n < $elements->length; $n++) {
    $item = $elements->item($n);
    $href = $item->getAttribute('href');
    // here's your href attribute
}
```

Comment: Great! Elegant and efficient solution! Great piece of advice too! Thanks!

Comment: @LinusKleen Why is it a bad thing? I have yet to understand why parsing HTML with regex is a bad thing. Oh and that guy didn't explain why, he just ranted. An explanation would help!

Comment: @Mob: The rant is indeed pointless (and without educative effect). When people say "parsing HTML" they actually mean "extraction". For which and in simple cases like that regular expressions are more than sufficient. For correctly parsing SGML and HTML (not so much XML and XHTML) you however need way more complex PCRE patterns.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491 - It's just that the advise became a meme on SO and now the cursorily (and incorrect) answer is to never use regex. (Should depend on use case+effort.)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
href\s*=\s*"([^#"]+#?[^"]*)"
```

Answer (score 1):

**First and foremost: DON'T USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML**

---

I would go with something like:

```
href=("|')?([^\s"'])+("|')?
```